# ng-repeat @font-face style not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, svg

I'm dynamically creating a list of fonts that are stored on my server. I want to `ng-repeat` through the list of fonts and apply each font to a new element.

So this is what I'm doing:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4" ng-repeat="font in ctrl.fontList">
        <style>
            @font-face {font-family:"{{font.family}}"; src: url({{font.url}});}
        </style>
        <svg height="100%" width="100%" position>
          <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#288feb"></rect>
          <g class="groupLayer">
              <text fill="#ffffff" x="0" y="0" font-size="48" font-family="{{font.family}}"
>{{ctrl.text}}</text>
          </g>
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>
```

This might be a big no-no in html but I have my `style` within my `div` as I wasn't trying to get this to work any way possible.

Anyway, this isn't working for me.

The `{{font.family}}` outputs `OstrichSans-Black` and the `{{font.url}}` is locally hosted on my `localhost` and the url is valid.

Any ideas why this isn't working? What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the issue was.. and it's really frustrating that this was the problem...

Very simply, I forgot to put quotation marks around my `url` parameter within the `@font-face`. That was literally the reason!

Answer (score 0):

Try applying the font via style instead:

```
<text style="font-family: '{{font.family}}';">
```

Comment: Don't forget quotes around the font family. Or, better yet, use `ng-style`.

Comment: No that just defaults to the `body` font... even with an `!important` on it

Comment: @Katie instead of using templating try my snippet with the name of the font you're loading. font-family: 'FontName';

Answer (score 0):

What version of you angularjs ? while test you code, i using 1.2.x and doesn't work with you code. After update to angular 1.4.8 this works:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
 
app.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
     var ctrl = this;
  ctrl.fontList = [
    {
        "family": "Abhaya Libre",
        "url": "https://cdn.rawgit.com/mooniak/abhaya-libre-font/gh-pages/fonts/AbhayaLibre-Regular.otf"
    },
    {
        "family": "Gemunu Libre",
        "url": "https://cdn.rawgit.com/mooniak/gemunu-libre-font/gh-pages/tests/fonts/GemunuLibre-Regular.otf"
    },
  ];
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="row" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController as ctrl">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4" ng-repeat="font in ctrl.fontList">
        <style>
            @font-face {font-family:{{font.family}}; src: url({{font.url}});}
        </style>
        <svg height="100%" width="100%" position>
          <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#288feb"></rect>
          <g class="groupLayer">
              <text fill="#ffffff" x="0" y="50" font-size="48" style="font-family:{{font.family}}"
>{{font.family}}</text>
          </g>
        </svg>
        
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: note: compare this answer with you code, because i make small changes.